# Formatting this particular array

Tags: formatting

I'm doing an assignment for my optimization course and I want to present my problem statement in LaTeX the same way my lecturer has in his notes, but I'm not sure how to go about it. This is an example from one of his worked examples. [image]

My instinct is to use the align environment or something similar, but I'm not sure how I would then get the $x \in \mathbb R^5$ part where it is.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to tex.stackexchange.com!  Please try to include a minimum working example (MWE) in your questions to make it easier for users to answer your question.

Comment: I didn't have a working example.

Comment: Your instructor will probably be pleased that you want to use `TeX` for your assignment. Perhaps if you ask he will share the source for his notes, so you can learn faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, by setting the two halves in a `array`.  The choice of a 15pt stacking gap is chosen to vertically match the "Subject to" text to the "`c_1(x)`" equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{?}
\setstackgap{L}{15pt}
\begin{document}
The optimization problem is\bigskip
\[\begin{array}{cc}
\Longunderstack{Minimize? $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$? Subject to} &
\begin{aligned}[t]
f(x) &= -0.043x_1 ...\\
 & \\
c_1(x) &= x_1...\\
c_2(x) &= -x_2...\\
c_3(x) &= 0.6 x_1...\\
c_4(x) &= 4 x_1...
\end{aligned}
\end{array}
\]
More text goes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one can jettison the `array` environment and, instead, manually stick the gap between the two columns (done here with `\quad`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{?}
\setstackgap{L}{15pt}
\begin{document}
The optimization problem is\bigskip
\[
\Longunderstack{Minimize? $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$? Subject to} \quad
\begin{aligned}[t]
f(x) &= -0.043x_1 ...\\
 & \\
c_1(x) &= x_1...\\
c_2(x) &= -x_2...\\
c_3(x) &= 0.6 x_1...\\
c_4(x) &= 4 x_1...
\end{aligned}
\]
More text goes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

using just `align` and `\underset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\noindent
The optimization problem is
\begin{align*}
\underset{\textstyle x \in \mathbb{R}^5}{\text{Minimize\strut}} \quad
 & f(x) = -0.043x_1 - 0.027x_2 - 0.025x_3 - 0.022x_4 - 0.045x_5 \\
\text{Subject to} \quad
 & \begin{aligned}[t]
   c_1(x) &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 - 10 \le 0 \,, \\
   c_2(x) &= -x_2 - x_3 - x_4 + 0.4 \le 0 \,, \\
   c_3(x) &= 0.6 x_1 + 0.6x_2 - 0.4x_3 - 0.4x_4 + 3.6x_5 \le 0 \,, \\
   c_4(x) &= 4 x_1 + 10x_2 -x_3 -2x_4 -3x_5 \le 0 \,.
 \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

the `\strut` is applied to `\text{Minimize\strut}` to provide depth, since the word has no descenders.

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, with `alignat*` and a tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

The optimization problem is\bigskip
\begin{alignat*}{2}
      & \eqmakebox[S][l]{Minimise} & \qquad & f(\mathbf{x})= -0.043x₁ ... \\[-1ex]
    & \eqmakebox[S]{$ \mathbf x ∈ \mathbb{R}⁵ $} \\[0.5ex]
    & \eqmakebox[S][l]{Subject to} &\MoveEqLeft[0.6]
    \mathrlap{ \begin{array}[t]{|@{\,}l}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    c₁(x) &= x₁...\\
    c₂(x) &= -x₂...\\
    c₃(x) &= 0.6 x₁...\\
    c₄(x) &= 4 x₁...
    \end{aligned}
    \end{array}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]